# Alternatives to const instance variables in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, oop

Since Objective-C doesn't support const instance variables in classes what are some alternatives to ensure the value of the variable doesn't get changed? I do not want to resort to preprocessor #defines because I would prefer class variables. Also, is there a reason const instance variables aren't supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects in Objective-C are constructed differently than those in C++ or Java.  All instance variables are initialized to zero by the `alloc` method, before the `init` method is called, so it would be too late by the time `init` is called to change a `const` instance variable.  Obviously the compiler writers could modify the compiler to support changing a `const` instance variable in an `init` method, but they haven't done so.

Typically you just make your instance variables `@private` and expose them using accessor methods.  If you don't want an instance variable's value to change, don't expose a setter method and don't modify the variable in your class implementation.

If you drop support for 32-bit Mac OS X, you can put your instance variables in your `@implementation` instead of your `@interface`, which completely protects them from meddling by other classes.

Comment: `@instance`??  Did you mean to say `@interface`?  I've never heard of the `@instance` keyword, and the latest Xcode doesn't have much to say _(highlight or complete)_ regarding it either.